# Shape round rect too large to be rendered into a texture in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, gridview

I am using a custom shape for the custom gridview.

The grid view attribute :

```
<com.View.UI.ExpandableHeightGridView
    android:id="@+id/issueList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/archiveTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
/>
```

the custom class extend gridview (which is use for increase the height when the element is add to the gridview)

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView{
    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {   
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

//            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
//            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

And the custom_shape.xml

```
<solid android:color="#FFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#808080" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" />
```

It works on my phone (more new) but when it run on the old tablet it show `Shape round rect too large to be rendered into a texture` , it is a gridview than contain ~ 40 element so it may be tall.

How to fix it?